# PostgreSQL - How to find the constraint path given two table name

Tags: postgresql

In my little world, let's say that I have the following example.

I have a postgresql database with over 50 tables and all the tables properly constrained in one fashion or another to each other.  Meaning that there isn't a single table that is just sitting out in the middle of the schema that isn't constrained to something.

How can I, given two table names, find the properly contained 'path' to build an SQL statement?

The example below, loosely, shows how the tables are constrained by foreign keys.

```
Table A -> Table B -> Table C -> Table D
           Table B -> Table E
```

Given that I start in "Table A" how can I find the path constraints if I'm wanting records out of "Table D".  The same question can be asked if I start in "Table A" and need records out of "Table E".  The unique problem is that I won't know until runtime what table I need the records out of.

In past research, INFORMATION_SCHEMA might be a place to start.

Is there a way to build a path at runtime?

[image: schemaModel]

-UPDATE-

So now given the new information of the table schema model that I uploaded.  For example, I'm looking for the FK path to the PART_FAMILIES table given a starting point of MATERIALS.  Practically speaking MATERIALS could be another table, but how do I get the path at runtime.  And... Thanks for the advice so far.

Comment: You could try to build a recursive query on pg_constraint, but this is extremely hard, especially if your data model contains loops.

Comment: Excellent point @wildplasser.  My data model is completely looped with constraints.  Not a single table exists anywhere that could not link back to another table.

Comment: It is not impossible to detect the loops, so at least you can avoid infinite recursion. Another point is composite FK's; these are hard to handle technically, caused by the arrays in pg_constraint.

Comment: You might find https://github.com/decibel/cat_tools/blob/master/sql/cat_tools.sql#L102 (mostly stolen from pgTap) somewhat useful. A recursive CTE could detect loops by incrementing a field every time it recurses; that would allow you to prevent infinite recursion. Ironically, what you really need to do this is a graph database.